# how to FTP file from windows machine to linux machine

Tags: java, ftp

How to transfer a file over FTP from my local Windows machine to a server Linux machine, that to the folder location can only be opened with a username and password.

How to do that, I know, how to move one file from one location to another location on the same machine.

Thanks.

Comment: you should probably add some information on whether you are attempting to do this programatically or if you just want to manually FTP a file as you haven't described how you want to do it in your question.

Comment: Does it mean something that you've tagged this question `java`? Or are you just hoping that it magically becomes programming-related if you throw in the name of a programming language as one of the tags? I don't see any mention in your question that you actually want to accomplish this in Java. Consider editing your question to include a discussion of things you've already tried, or at least what you've considered.

Comment: @All : I mean that this thing I want to achieve with Java only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You flagged the question with **Java**, so I assume you want do this programmatically.

> - JScape, iNet Factory: com.jscape.inet.ftp.Ftp
> - In software, IP*Works: ipworks.Ftp
> - Enterprise Distributed Technologies, Java FTP Client Library:
>     com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient
> - IBM alphaWorks, FTP Bean Suite: com.ibm.network.ftp.protocol.FTPProtocol
> - SourceForge, JFtp: net.sf.jftp.net.FtpConnection
> - The Jakarta Project, Jakarta Commons/Net:
>     org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
> - JavaShop JNetBeans: jshop.jnet.FTPClient
> - Sun, JDK: sun.net.ftp.FtpClient
> - Florent Cueto, JavaFTP API: com.cqs.ftp.FTP
> - Bea Petrovicova, jFTP: cz.dhl.ftp.Ftp
> - The Globus Project, Java CoG Kit: org.globus.io.ftp.FTPClient
>
> Reference: [Java FTP client libraries](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0404-ftp.html?page=2)